# Geoserver print plugin Mapfish error

Tags: geoserver, printing, mapfish

**I'm trying to print one wms layer with openstreetmap base map.
Although I get a pdf file, it is empty with following errors:**

```
java.io.IOException: Permission denied (Bind failed)
java.io.IOException: Permission denied (Bind failed)
java.io.IOException: Permission denied (Bind failed)
java.io.IOException: Permission denied (Bind failed)
java.io.IOException: Error (status=302) while reading the image from https://****/geoserver/wms?BBOX=-2878582.495003635%2C932558.2924218667%2C-2257693.5923343645%2C1614124.9590885332&HEIGHT=503&WIDTH=458&TRANSPARENT=true&map_resolution=75&VERSION=1.1.1&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TILED=true&SERVICE=WMS&format_options=dpi%3A75&LAYERS=ensad%3Ahydropower&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&DPI=75&SRS=EPSG%3A900913: Found
```

**Here is geoserver's log:**

```
2017-02-23 03:10:43,681 ERROR [org.mapfish.print.PDFUtils] - Server returned an error for http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/06/26/30.png: Permission denied (Bind failed)
2017-02-23 03:10:43,682 ERROR [org.mapfish.print.PDFUtils] - Server returned an error for http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/06/27/30.png: Permission denied (Bind failed)
2017-02-23 03:10:43,682 ERROR [org.mapfish.print.PDFCustomBlocks] - Error while adding a PDF elementjava.io.IOException: Permission denied (Bind failed)
2017-02-23 03:10:43,682 ERROR [org.mapfish.print.PDFCustomBlocks] - Error while adding a PDF elementjava.io.IOException: Permission denied (Bind failed)
2017-02-23 03:10:43,683 ERROR [org.mapfish.print.PDFUtils] - Server returned an error for http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/06/27/29.png: Permission denied (Bind failed)
2017-02-23 03:10:43,684 ERROR [org.mapfish.print.PDFUtils] - Server returned an error for http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/06/26/29.png: Permission denied (Bind failed)
2017-02-23 03:10:43,685 ERROR [org.mapfish.print.PDFCustomBlocks] - Error while adding a PDF elementjava.io.IOException: Permission denied (Bind failed)
2017-02-23 03:10:43,685 ERROR [org.mapfish.print.PDFCustomBlocks] - Error while adding a PDF elementjava.io.IOException: Permission denied (Bind failed)
2017-02-23 03:10:43,685 ERROR [org.mapfish.print.PDFUtils] - Server returned an error for https://****/geoserver/wms?BBOX=-3583420.7430280354%2C868930.7117841667%2C-2962531.840358765%2C1550497.3784508333&HEIGHT=503&WIDTH=458&TRANSPARENT=true&map_resolution=75&VERSION=1.1.1&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TILED=true&SERVICE=WMS&format_options=dpi%3A75&LAYERS=ensad%3hydropower&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&DPI=75&SRS=EPSG%3A900913: Error (status=302) while reading the image from https://****/geoserver/wms?BBOX=-3583420.7430280354%2C868930.7117841667%2C-2962531.840358765%2C1550497.3784508333&HEIGHT=503&WIDTH=458&TRANSPARENT=true&map_resolution=75&VERSION=1.1.1&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TILED=true&SERVICE=WMS&format_options=dpi%3A75&LAYERS=ensad%3hydropower&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&DPI=75&SRS=EPSG%3A900913: Found
2017-02-23 03:10:43,685 ERROR [org.mapfish.print.PDFCustomBlocks] - Error while adding a PDF elementjava.io.IOException: Error (status=302) while reading the image from https://****/geoserver/wms?BBOX=-3583420.7430280354%2C868930.7117841667%2C-2962531.840358765%2C1550497.3784508333&HEIGHT=503&WIDTH=458&TRANSPARENT=true&map_resolution=75&VERSION=1.1.1&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TILED=true&SERVICE=WMS&format_options=dpi%3A75&LAYERS=ensad%3Anatural_gas&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&DPI=75&SRS=EPSG%3A900913: Found
```

I'm using SSL for both geoserver and app. and both geoserver and app. is in same server.